# Firebase suddenly started to give `file not found` error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm using pods for installing `Firebase`:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

but today suddenly it started to give me the next 2 errors:

```
'FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h' file not found
```

and

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
```

yesterday it worked perfectly and I did not changed anything or run `pod install`. So I do not know why this error appears!

I've tried to reinstall it, removed Podfile.lock and .xcworkspace file — nothing. The errors still stay there.

How can I fix the problem and why it appeared suddenly?

Comment: see if your project will build. I sometimes have this problem with alamofire where xcode doesn't recognize files until the project builds for the first time since the pod was added.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I'm in porting our project in a new machine and suddenly we are getting these errors as well.